# SSIS - how to make the control flow continue before the current step is complete?

Tags: ssis

I have a query that polls a table for scheduled ETL tasks to initiate. The query gives me the package name and the required parameters to be fed to it. I want to execute all of them in parallel, but because the number of scheduled tasks to run is dynamic, I'm using a ForEach looper to iterate through each row returned by my query, and likewise execute them dynamically. This seems most decidedly serial, not parallel. What I want to happen is for the Control Flow to start the SSIS package and continue on to the next iteration, start the next package, etc., instead of waiting for one package to finish before starting the next.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The exact solution depends on the details of the application but as a general approach I would suggest to read the table into one or more variable and use the value of these variables as a precedence constraint to execute the packages accordingly. This will avoid the use of the for loop and will provide parallelism.

Another solution to explore is SQL Server Agent, which does a decent job in most of the cases.

SSIS example. Let's say we read the tasks from sql server into variables RunTask1,RunTask2,RunTask3,RunTask4 and RunTask5. We'll run the corresponding task if the value of the variable is 1 and will not run for any other value. The picture below show how to use this data as precedence constraints (task 3 in the example):

[image]

Comment: Using a precendence constraint sounds like an interesting alternative, but I'm not sure I'm following. If I've loaded the table of queued tasks into a variable, how do I read that from the precendence constraint control? Also, how exactly would that provide parallelism? Maybe you could give me an example of what you mean..?

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: Thanks for this. What if, for example, I had multiple instances of Task 1 (with different parameters, of course) that needed to run in parallel, though?